# Launch jupyter-lab and open a specific notebook from the command line?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm writing a bash script that ends by launching jupyter-lab and (ideally) opening a specific notebook.

In jupyter, this is easy to do:

`$ jupyter notebook my_folder/my_notebook.ipynb`

I can't find any guidance for how to do this in jupyter-lab. Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems not to be documented in great detail but there are at least two ways of opening specific files:

Simply using the `jupyter lab` command (see [this comment](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5056#issuecomment-410666802))

```sh
$ jupyter lab my_folder/my_notebook.ipynb
```

or using the [Jupyter URLs](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#url-tree). First, you start the jupyter lab server, without browser and then open an URL locating the file of choice:

```sh
$ jupyter lab --no-browser &
$ sensible-browser http(s)://<server:port>/<lab-location>/lab/tree/path/to/notebook.ipynb
```

where `sensible-browser` can be replaced by the browser of your choice (e.g. `google-chrome` or `firefox`) and specific URL parts can be retrieved from the URL displayed by the first command (possibly one could extract and assemble the URL automatically).

The Jupyter URLs seem to be a bit more customizable (offering the choice of workspace, etc).

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked to navigate to the directory and running:

```
$ jupyter lab my_notebook.ipynb
```

So no path is needed if you are already in the directory.