# How to add a README to a jupyter lab tree view

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm running Jupyter lab on a Docker container inside an AWS EC2 instance , so other colleagues can access it. I'm launching Jupyter using the following Docker command:

`sudo docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook:17aba6048f44`

I'd like to have some kind of README or initial text when they first access Jupyter (when going to the URL http://x.y.z.w:8888/tree) with some instructions of what they should do.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How are you running your JupyterLab instance? Is this using JupyterHub of some kind? When starting JupyterLab from command line you can open an arbitrary file by simply specifying its name (it requires a recent version of JupyterLab), like: `jupyter lab README.md`. I think that including more information may be needed for an answer about a specific setting (like JupyterHub), but I also added an answer for a general use-case of providing a tour to the users (probably best suited for larger deployments with dozens/hundreds of users where it really pays off).

Comment: Also, you can create a URL pointing to a specific file as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56304230/6646912

Comment: Thank you @krassowski. I've edited my original question with more info on how I'm running JupyterLab (on a Docker container). Might need to see if the starting page can be changed when starting Juypter on Docker.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to do a little bit of scripting, you can create beautiful interactive tours using the [jupyterlab-tour](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyterlab-tour) extension, like this:

[image: gif from jupyterlab-tour page]

It already includes a welcome tour if you just want to give your users an overview of JupyterLab.

If you would want to create your custom tour, the example in the readme is a good place to start:

```js
const { commands } = app;
// Add a tour - returns the tour or null if something went wrong
const tour = (await app.commands.execute('jupyterlab-tour:add', {
  tour: { // Tour must be of type ITour - see src/tokens.ts
    id: 'test-jupyterlab-tour:welcome',
    label: 'Welcome Tour',    
    hasHelpEntry: true,
    steps: [  // Step must be of type IStep - see src/tokens.ts
      {
        content:
          'The following tutorial will point out some of the main UI components within JupyterLab.',
        placement: 'center',
        target: '#jp-main-dock-panel',
        title: 'Welcome to Jupyter Lab!'
      },
      {
        content:
          'This is the main content area where notebooks and other content can be viewed and edited.',
        placement: 'left-end',
        target: '#jp-main-dock-panel',
        title: 'Main Content'
      }
    ]
  }
})) as ITour;
if ( tour ) {
  app.commands.execute('jupyterlab-tour:launch', {
    id: 'test-jupyterlab-tour:welcome',
    force: false  // Optional, if false the tour will start only if the user have not seen or skipped it
  })
}
```

However, you would likely want to follow the [JupyterLab extension tutorial](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_tutorial.html) first to understand what is happening in the code above and how to compile it. You will also benefit from using the [extension developer guide](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html) as reference.