# how to programmatically open a notebook in jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have markdown pages with links to various notebooks.
I want to open some of these notebooks in a given server,
(i.e., more than one notebook.)

I found [Launch jupyter-lab and open a specific notebook from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56301712/launch-jupyter-lab-and-open-a-specific-notebook-from-the-command-line)
which suggests using

```
$ jupyter lab --no-browser &
$ sensible-browser http(s)://<server:port>/<lab-location>/lab/tree/path/to/notebook.ipynb
```

this almost does what I want:
each invocation of `sensible-browser` uses the running server on the given port.

It does however open a new browser tab each time,
rather than adding the notebook to the existing tab.

Is there a way to have each of the notebooks run in the same `http://localhost:<port>` tab?

Comment: What's usually done is launch JupyterLab and have it open a notebook that has markdown in it with links to the notebooks. Then you can launch the notebooks as tabs in that JupyterLab session. Example on a remote session using MyBinder.org to serve JupyterLab: [click here to spin up session with example](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/pdbepisa-binder/HEAD?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree%2Findex.ipynb). Your solution may need to be different; however, hopefully it gives you an example. (Example is based on [the repo here](https://github.com/fomightez/pdbepisa-binder), but you wanted JupyterLab.)

Comment: If you needed something fancier, you may be able to control what opens in JupyterLab programmatically via [ipylab](https://github.com/jtpio/ipylab#ipylab). Also, maybe what you are looking for is JupyterLab's 'workspaces', see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-hidden-features-in-jupyterlab-you-should-start-using-bfd9402464ca). Note the link [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html#url-workspaces-ui) says, "Workspaces save their state on the server and can be shared between multiple users (or browsers) as long as they have access to the same server.".